# How to make word wrap in android studio by default

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, word-wrap

When I write something on the android studio, the line goes on over the right screen. How do I turn on word soft wrap in android studio?

[image]

Answer (score 70):

If you are on mac and want to soft wrap just the current active Editor, here is how to do it: - 
On the menu bar 
**View -> Active Editor -> Soft-Wrap**

Comment: Worked for Windows 10 too.

Comment: This is not. Other answers point to Settings. This answer provides the quickest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 31):

Please goto **"File->Settings->Editor->General"** tab and check **"Use soft wraps in editor"**. it will solve your problem.

Updates: As @ThePartyTurtle mentioned on the comment some versions of Android Studio specifically from v3.5.3 This option is available via

**Android Studio->Preferences...->Editor->General**

[image]

Comment: An update to this answer: In my instance of Android Studio v3.5.3, you can now find "Soft Wraps" settings via "Android Studio"->"Preferences..."->"Editor"->"General".

Comment: Thanks @ThePartyTurtle, I updated my answer to include what you mentioned on the comment.

Answer (score 7):

You go to Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General > Soft Wraps

then you have to indicate what type of documents you want the soft wrap to be applied on. Be sure to separate each type with a semicolon.

example: *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc; *.dart; *.plist;

[Image that complements the explanation of the menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1DJ4.png)

Comment: "Be sure to separate each type with a semicolon" FTW :)

Answer (score 6):

File>Settings>Editor>General
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's my 2 cents:

A quick way to toggle word-wraps:

**Ctrl + Shit + A**  :  *(opens a search window with "Actions" tab enabled.)*

Type `Soft wrap`

Press enter on the first search-result: `View | Active Editor Soft-wrap`

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

1. File > Settings > General
2. Tick the "Soft-wrap these files:" checkbox, and write `*.*`
3. Apply > OK

Comment: For Android Studio 4.x. Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 4):

If u want to use soft wrap by default go through the following steps

step-1 : Click on view ( in Navigation bar )
step-2 : Choose Active Editor
step-3 : Click on Soft wrap

that's it ...

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Android Studio Arctic Fox Solution

From the menu:
**File > Settings > General**
Tick the **Soft-wrap these files** checkbox.

[image: Settings in Android Studio Arctic Fox]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on mac: **Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Soft-wrap these files**

If you are on Windows : **Settings > Editor > General > Soft-wrap these files**

**To enable Soft-wrap, write the following code in the box in front of the checkbox**

1. `*.*` to wrap all the files in the editor
2. `*.<extension_of_file>` to wrap files with specific extension an separated by semicolon

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.